# Controlled Pump Component - Initialization error - Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a hydraulic system on Modelica. When I add `Controlled Pump` into the system, i get initialization errors.

> Error occured when entering initialization mode on Hochdruckreiniger4_1
> Initialize
>
> Error encountered in the Initialize function of user model

Could you help me to solve this problem? I add below images of the settings of the model so that you can understand better the settings. I give required initialization values. But I get still errors relating to initialization. Thanks in advance for yor helps!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
model Hochdruckreiniger4
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real N = 2800;
    replaceable package medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater( );
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary1 (p = 500e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile (dp_nominal = 95, m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile (dp_nominal = 94.35, m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Pulse Puls2 (period = 0.02142, startTime = 0.01071, width = 45.331);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Pulse Puls1 (period = 0.02142, width = 45.331);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe5 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.3,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        momentumDynamics = system.momentumDynamics,
        massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        energyDynamics = system.energyDynamics,
        allowFlowReversal = system.allowFlowReversal,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe4 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        momentumDynamics = system.momentumDynamics,
        massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        energyDynamics = system.energyDynamics,
        allowFlowReversal = system.allowFlowReversal,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe3 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        momentumDynamics = system.momentumDynamics,
        massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        energyDynamics = system.energyDynamics,
        allowFlowReversal = system.allowFlowReversal,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe2 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        momentumDynamics = system.momentumDynamics,
        massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        energyDynamics = system.energyDynamics,
        allowFlowReversal = system.allowFlowReversal,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system;
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.ControlledPump pump1 (
        p_a_nominal = 4e5,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05,
        control_m_flow = false,
        rho_nominal = 990,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        N_nominal = 2800,
        p_set = 550e5,
        use_p_set = true,
        p_a_start = 4e5,
        p_b_start = 550e5,
        m_flow_start = 0.05,
        T_start = 293,
        use_T_start = true,
        allowFlowReversal = false,
        energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        V = 0,
        massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        s(start = 1e-2),
        N(start = 2800),
        V_flow_single(start = 1));


equation
    //Connection(s)
    connect(boundary1.ports[1], pipe4.port_b);
    connect(HDVentile.opening, Puls2.y);
    connect(HDVentile.port_b, pipe4.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile.port_a, pipe3.port_b);
    connect(NDVentile.opening, Puls1.y);
    connect(NDVentile.port_b, pipe2.port_a);
    connect(NDVentile.port_a, pipe5.port_b);
    connect(pipe5.port_a, boundary.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe2.port_b, pump1.port_a);
    connect(pump1.port_b, pipe3.port_a);
end  Hochdruckreiniger4;
```

Comment: Not really a solution, but potentially of help: Dymola complains that pressure is too low for the medium (varying values ranging from approx. -10e6 to 600Pa) and, following that, temperate seems to be below 273.15K. Then initialization fails - which seems reasonable as the water is frozen at initialization...

Comment: Are the valves closed at the beginning? If yes, adjust the pulse sources such that the valves are open at initialization.

Comment: ND - Ventile is open at the beginning. When ND-Ventile is closed , then the other valve will be open. They operate such that one of them is open all the time. Apart from that, I tried to simulate for the case when both is open at the beginning. But still I have the same error.